# The body might complete normally, causing 'null' to be returned, but the return type, 'Widget', is a potentially non-nullable type

Tags: flutter, dart, dart-null-safety

I'm a beginner Flutter developer,my code gives me errors.

I'm building a simple todo list application and I use the list builder for the todo list to build

while using item `ListView.builder` the error shown I am not able to figure out how to solve this please help me out thanks in advance for helping

```
class TodoListState extends State<todoList> {
  final List<String> _todoItems = [];

  // This will be called each time the + button is pressed
  void _addTodoItem() {
    // Putting our code inside "setState" tells the app that our state has changed, and
    // it will automatically re-render the list
    setState(() {
      int index = _todoItems.length;
      _todoItems.add('Item ' + index.toString());
    });
  }

  // Build the whole list of todo items
  Widget _buildTodoList() {
    return  ListView.builder(
     itemBuilder: (context, index){ 
        // I get =>  The body might complete normally, causing 'null' to be returned, but the return type, 'Widget', is a potentially non-nullable type
        if(index < _todoItems.length) {
          return _buildTodoItem(_todoItems[index]);
        }
      },
    );
  }

  // Build a single todo item
  Widget _buildTodoItem(String todoText) {
    return  ListTile(
        title: Text(todoText)
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return  Scaffold(
      appBar:  AppBar(
          title: const Text('Todo List')
      ),
      body: _buildTodoList(),
      floatingActionButton:  FloatingActionButton(
          onPressed: _addTodoItem,
          tooltip: 'Add task',
          child: const Icon(Icons.add)
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: You dont need to check `index < _todoItems.length`, provide ` lenght : _todoItems.length,` it will handle the rest,  more about [ListView.builder](https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/lists/long-lists#2-convert-the-data-source-into-widgets)

Comment: this has worked```  itemCount: items.length,
          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
            return ListTile(
              title: Text(items[index]),
            );```     not the length one

Comment: Then I think you can accept @bayhas's answer.

Answer (score 1):

do this instead :

```dart
    Widget _buildTodoList() {
    return  ListView.builder(
     lenght : _todoItems.length,
     itemBuilder: (context, index){ 

        return _buildTodoItem(_todoItems[index]);
      },
    );
  }
```